# Highcharts more than 2 x axies

Tags: highcharts, axis

I would like to add more than 2 x axies (datetime series) on the same highchart graph. I can see that Highcharts allows only dual x axis and no more than 2 x axis allowed.

Is there any way to do some workaround to address more than 2 datetime x axis ?

Comment: > "according to highcharts, its only allowing dual x-axis and no more than 2 x axis allowed"

That is not true. Where did you find this information?

Answer (score 0):

You can define as many axes as you want.

Example with 3 datetime x-axes (Click button to add more): http://jsfiddle.net/1s62gh68/1/

```
xAxis: [{
            type: 'datetime',
            maxZoom: 48 * 3600 * 1000
        }, {
            type: 'datetime',
            maxZoom: 48 * 3600 * 1000
        }, {
            type: 'datetime',
            opposite: true,
            maxZoom: 48 * 3600 * 1000
        }],
```